# Swift 3 - Open URL from JSON in Safari

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I currently have a mobile app that brings in a list of items from a JSON file. 
The JSON file also has a list of urls attached to each item. 
I need to open the URL in Safari when the user touches the item in the list view.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) 
    cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row] 
    return cell 
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this, I can post code to display how I bring in the list of data if necessary.

Comment: show your list view code...`cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `DidSelectRow`

Comment: not here, add this to your question, it will be lot easier to read.

Comment: thanks, I don't have anything for DidSelectRow yet as I haven't got that far.

Comment: please post the structure of your JSON and where you stored it. otherwise we cannot answer

Answer (score 1):

Add this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:TableData[indexPath.row])!)
}
```

Comment: Thanks will have a look, just realised I need two add a Main item, then which goes into sub items when selected first. Will work that out before I implement this function